# How to send captcha interface to windows form?

Tags: c#, selenium, captcha

I am trying to make an automated bot, and the website requires a captcha to be solved. When the task gets to that captcha I would like the captcha to appear on the windows form, as I am running the chrome instance in headless selenium. How would I go about this? I'm using C#. I could have the browser open, but I am looking to run this in headless. Thank you!

I've tried syncing the chrome profile but it doesn't seem to work 100% of the time. Here is my attempt:

```
 public void loginToChrome()
{
    DGDriver.Url = "https://accounts.google.com/signin/chrome/sync/identifier?ssp=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&flowName=GlifDesktopChromeSync";
    DGDriver.FindElement(By.Id("identifierId")).SendKeys(email + OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
    DGDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
    DGDriver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys(password + OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
    DGDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
    DGDriver.Url = "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox";
}
```

I tried logging into google so that the captcha doesn't appear, but that doesn't seem to be working either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please specify what "it doesn't seem to work 100% of the time" means? I.e. is there an error message, erroneous output, etc. that could help us in trying to answer your question? :)

Comment: Ohhh correct me if I'm wrong: you meant you tried syncing the chrome profile **as a way to prevent being asked for the captcha** but it doesn't work every time?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.